# Vim start-up extremely slow under Cygwin when fugitive.vim plugin is installed

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, vim-fugitive, puttycyg

I've just started running Vim under cygwin via puttycyg. I find this much better than gVim under windows ;)

Anyway, the fugitive.vim plugin causes Vim to take 15-20 seconds to startup. After Vim has started, everything seems normal. I can use fugitive.vim as normal from that point on.

What could be the cause of this slowness? Something to do with cygwin I bet... Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem using vim.exe from MobaXterm. Except Vim seems to never start, and consumes 50% CPU until the end of times...

Comment: Wow, thanks for posting this question - I was just trying to figure out why my Vim installation starts so slowly under Cygwin! Sure enough I'm running into the same problem you are with fugitive.vim.

Comment: @pho79 - No worries mate. I haven't worked out what the issue is yet unfortunately. Luckily though I use windows/svn at work and osx/git at home, so I can just disable fugitive.vim in my Cygwin installation for the time being. If you work out what is causing the problem though, please do let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Git in general in cygwin seems to be slow. The bashrc settings that modify my prompt based on git status is lightning fast on OSX and Linux, and takes about a half-second or longer on Cygwin's bash. Other git operations are similarly slow by comparison on Cygwin. I suspect the underlying library that fugitive uses.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after trying everything people suggested, I re-installed my cygwin packages/tools and vim is now very fast.

Comment: I've tried this, but after a while it start again.. That cause me stress a lot.. I usually code on go and this's go no go.... The vim is very slow on cygwin, and I have tried anything... But on my android termux it run fast.... Oh dear...